# app data loss on version upgrade

Tags: ios, sqlite

although this is an older question to ask, but i didn't got any suitable solution for this. That's why i am asking for help about this issue.

I have an iphone app, which contains a sqlite db in it's resource folder. Now, when i upgrade it to the later version from iTunes, all the data in the database are lost.

Suppose a user entered 1000 entry in the database. So if he lost his data in case of upgrading the application from iTunes, he will definitely not gonna love to upgrade his app's version. He should be then notified first that, "you will loss all of your previous data" or the previous data should be kept unchanged in the new version.

What procedure i should follow in the new version to keep all the old data in the new version...?

I can't modify the previous versions. So, i have to do something in the latest version so that all the data from the previous version should be kept in this newer one.

This is an emergency problem. Users are upgrading the application & they are loosing their previously stored data in the database. Even they are not being notified that they will lost all the data. !

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Comment: Didn't solved it yet. I'm not working on that project anymore.

Comment: @Nico Did you find any solution for it? Using CoreData?

Comment: I know that questions is 6 years old, but how did you solve this issue? i'm struggling with the same problem now

Answer (score 5):

When not using Core Data, the only way to preserve user data is to store your database in the user **Documents** directory as well as the **Library** directory.

### Documents

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserData.sqlite"]];
```

### Library

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

These are also the only directories write-accessible to your app. If you have include a "blank" database in your **Resources** folder, it is copied to the bundle. From there, you need to check whether the db exists in the **Documents** directory, if not, then copy it from the bundle.

This is the only way to ensure that data is protected on app upgrades.

On another note, if the user does not backup their device, uninstalls the app then re0installs the app, the data will be gone.

In regards to the user not being notified they will lose their data, the only thing that will prompt the user about loss of data is when they decide to remove the app from the device, or if you implement some way to notify the user of any data change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I'll definitely try this out later on today. Seems it will work. But the problem is that, the application is already live in Appstore. So, now i don't know whether the problem can be solved or not for the previous version, if i keep the sqlite database in the Documents directory. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store your data? You are supposed to do it in `Documents` directory of your application bundle. Directories other then `Documents` and `Library` are not preserved during app updates (During update your app is actually installed in other directory, and its data is copied back).

Here's a good overview of iOS file system: [iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside (File System Programming Guide)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1)

Comment: I've stored my data into a sqlite database. That sqlite database has been stored in the Resource folder of the application.
Thanks for the link. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a separate sqlite db file for user's data  which you should not loss.

PS: When new update is downloading from App Store. iOS moves old files to another folder. When download and installation complete iOS move old files to the application's folder.

Comment: I am facing the same issue,but still i am not able to trace the root cause.My problem is we are storing user login credential to the DB and on launch we are checking if the user has already logged in using SELECT query,but for our old customer who are already using my app and already logged in they are not able to login automatically by checking DB with SELECT query.We have made some changed to the new DB.Can you please explain why this is happening?(Let me know if my question is not clear to you)

Answer (score 0):

If you would have **set the version number** to your database for your iphone could have been easily handle, save your version number into your db and whenever database is called, **compare the version against the expected version**

If `new version > older version` change the schema (this is needed if you would have changed the schema of your database) with using SQL ALTER statements and update the app version number.

So whenever user is going to update or fresh installation, it will check the new version with your older version, if it differ then update schema, and if its same no need to make any changes.

> If you would not have made any schema related changes (for example
>   adding new column..) then you do not need to worry, user will not lose
>   the data.